# Is there a way to detect breaks in a TPL Dataflow graph

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I create fairly complex TPL Dataflow graphs, and often it happens that there is a break in the graph somewhere. The symptom of this is simply that the app hangs, because some of the dataflow blocks are waiting for messages.

Is there a way to detect when this happens, other than manually tracing the graph? I can see that there is a LinkedTargets property available in the debug view of a DataflowBlock - when I have a break this is set to 0. However since this is not public so I can't write something to automatically check for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection. The [TPL Dataflow Debugger Visualizer](https://dataflowdebuggerview.codeplex.com) uses reflection to retrieve the linked targets in [DataFlowBlockDebugInfoRetriever.GetInnerDataFlowDebuggerInfo](https://dataflowdebuggerview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/Core/DataFlowBlockDebugInfoRetriever.cs) and create a list of [nodes](https://dataflowdebuggerview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/Common/DataFlowDebuggerInfo.cs) for each block. It then creates a graph structure [using QuickGraph](https://dataflowdebuggerview.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/TPLDataFlowDebuggerVisualizer/ViewModel/DataFlowGraphViewModel.cs).

This structure can be visualized as the Visualizer does, or you can search it for partitions in code. Quickgraph already [implements several algorithms](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=User%20Manual) that may be of use.

A simpler solution though, would be to only search for non-ActionBlock blocks with 0 linked targets